# Krein - Smulian theorem - norm or weak closure?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The theorem of Krein - Smulian reads as follows: *The closed convex hull of a weakly compact subset of a Banach space is weakly compact.*

We consider the closed convex hull - but is it norm closure or weak closure?

I was thinking that maybe it does not matter. Every Banach space is locally convex which imples that closed convex hull is still convex and by Mazur lemma it is weakly closed. Unfortunatelly, I don't know if weak closure of a convex hull is still convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. It does not matter, because the weak and norm closure of a convex set are the same. As a result, the weak closure of a convex set is convex, because it is equal to the norm closure of the same convex set, and we know that norm-closures of convex sets are convex.